# How can I build MOCs well

Tags: moc

I want to learn to build MOCs well. Is there any advice or websites/videos that give building advice and techniques for building

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: While I've posted generic suggestion as an answer it is best to just begin building something yourself. And once you encounter an issue you cannot solve or need some advise - post this as a new question with as much details as you have. Make sure to add pictures as otherwise it is basically impossible to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather opinion based, however I've got a piece of advice.

General advice is to build whatever you want and as often as you can. It won't be perfect and top-level MOC at beginning (we all were there at point), but you will eventually get there, while learning following in the process:

- what it is to build for yourself;
- what kind of obstacles you encounter during your build;
- list of parts you can use and their properties;
- what colors are generally available for the MOCs you build;
- what it is to work with certain scale;
- structure stability;

and so on.

Next thing is to build other people's MOCs and study them. These are, sometimes, more advanced that LEGO sets. You can find a lot of free instructions on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/).

I've specifically excluded any resources for advanced techniques as those are usually cool to look, but are very specific to particular use case. There are also no resources that list *all* possible techniques, because... there's no such thing as "all techniques" - something is being discovered every other day!

**Disclaimer**. Wanted to post this as a comment, but it got too long.